# Interpreting an iterative procedure for inverse multiple scattering problem

Tags: asymptotics, physics, mathematical-physics, inverse-problems

I am trying to interpret the following computation:

[image]

Now, for the problem I am working on, which has some subtle differences, my interpretation is as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}
\hat{u}_\infty(\omega,\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{\xi})&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}V(\boldsymbol{x}')e^{i\omega\boldsymbol{\xi}'\cdot\boldsymbol{x}'/c}e^{-i\omega\boldsymbol{\xi}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}'/c}\,d\boldsymbol{x}'+\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}V(\boldsymbol{x}'_1)e^{-i\omega\boldsymbol{\xi}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}'_1/c}
\\
&\cdot\frac{e^{i\omega\|\boldsymbol{x}'_1-\boldsymbol{x}'_1\|/c}}{4\pi\|\boldsymbol{x}'_1-\boldsymbol{x}'_2\|}V(\boldsymbol{x}'_2)e^{i\omega\boldsymbol{\xi}'\cdot\boldsymbol{x}'_2/c}\,d\boldsymbol{x}'_2\,d\boldsymbol{x}'_1+...
\\
&...+\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}...\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}V(\boldsymbol{x}'_1)e^{i\omega\boldsymbol{\xi}'\cdot\boldsymbol{x}'/c}\cdot\frac{e^{i\omega\|\boldsymbol{x}'_1-\boldsymbol{x}'_2\|/c}}{4\pi\|\boldsymbol{x}'_1-\boldsymbol{x}'_2\|}
\\
&\cdot V(\boldsymbol{x}'_2)\cdot...\cdot V(\boldsymbol{x}'_n)e^{-i\omega\boldsymbol{\xi}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}'_n/c}\,d\boldsymbol{x}'_n...d\boldsymbol{x}'_1+...
\end{aligned}$$
Obviously, my $y$ is $x'$ and my $k$ is $\xi$...

Now, I don't understand what they mean by "if Fourier transforms are taken throughout", since the first term in my equation becomes

$$\hat{u}_\infty(\omega,\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{\xi})=\hat{V}(\omega(\boldsymbol{\xi}'-\boldsymbol{\xi})/c)+...$$

which is consistent with their computation (and does not involve any further Fourier transform). However, for the subsequent terms I don't understand what they've done nor how to interpret the $k'''$ et al?

**Edit:**

If I take Fourier transforms with respect to the $\boldsymbol{x}$ variable, then this gives:

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{F}_x\hat{u}_\infty(\omega,\boldsymbol{k},\boldsymbol{\xi})&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\mathcal{F}_x V(\boldsymbol{k}')e^{i\omega\boldsymbol{\xi}'\cdot\boldsymbol{k}'/c}e^{-i\omega\boldsymbol{\xi}\cdot\boldsymbol{k}'/c}\,d\boldsymbol{k}'+\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\mathcal{F}_x V(\boldsymbol{k}'_1)e^{-i\omega\boldsymbol{\xi}\cdot\boldsymbol{k}'_1/c}\frac{e^{i\omega\|\boldsymbol{k}'_1-\boldsymbol{k}'_2\|/c}}{4\pi\|\boldsymbol{k}'_1-\boldsymbol{k}'_2\|}
\\&\cdot V(\boldsymbol{k}'_2)e^{i\omega\boldsymbol{\xi}'\cdot\boldsymbol{k}'_2/c}\,d\boldsymbol{k}'_2\,d\boldsymbol{k}'_1+...+\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}...\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\mathcal{F}_x V(\boldsymbol{k}'_1)e^{i\omega\boldsymbol{\xi}'\cdot\boldsymbol{k}_1/c}\frac{e^{i\omega\|\boldsymbol{k}'_1-\boldsymbol{k}'_2\|/c}}{4\pi\|\boldsymbol{k}'_1-\boldsymbol{k}'_2\|}\\&\cdot V(\boldsymbol{k}'_2)\cdot...\cdot V(\boldsymbol{k}'_n)e^{-i\omega\boldsymbol{\xi}\cdot\boldsymbol{k}'_n/c}\,d\boldsymbol{k}'_n...d\boldsymbol{k}'_1+...\end{aligned}$$

Again, I can interpret the first addendum as $\mathcal{F}_x\hat{V}(\omega(\boldsymbol{\xi}'-\boldsymbol{\xi}/c)$, but I can't seem to equate the other addendums to something similar to what they have in the article...

Comment: [Born series for T-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_series#Born_series_for_T-matrix)

Comment: @KeithMcClary I'm using http://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1664766 to help me retrieve the potential $V(x)$. I already wrote out the Born series in one of my equations. I'm just struggling to figure out what has been done in the next step.

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't understand. They are just doing the operations in the Fourier domain, for example, if  $f(x) = \int A(x,y)B(y,z)g(z)dzdy$  then $\hat f(p) = \int \hat A(p,q)\hat B(q,r)\hat g(r)dqdr$.

Comment: @KeithMcClary May you check my edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second term is
$$\int V(k'-k'') \frac{1}{k''^2 - k^2}V(k'' - k) dk''$$

$$=\int \int e^{i(k'-k'')x}V(x)dx \frac{1}{k''^2 - k^2} \int e^{i(k''-k)y}V(y)dy dk''$$

$$=\int \int e^{ik'x} V(x) \left[\int e^{-ik''x} \frac{1}{k''^2 - k^2} e^{ik''y} dk''\right]  e^{-iky}V(y)dx dy$$

$$=\int \int e^{ik'x} V(x) \left[-2 \pi^2\frac{e^{i|k||x-y|}}{|x-y|}\right]  e^{-iky}V(y)dx dy$$

The last step is in [Max Kreuzer's Lecture Notes](http://hep.itp.tuwien.ac.at/~kreuzer/qt08.pdf) equations 8.107 and 8.115 .